# RIGHT JOIN in Oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have large Oracle query, but I would like to have a `RIGHT JOIN` on the below line of code, I tried to use (+) but does not work:

```
AND SUBSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, 0, INSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1) =
  SUBSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, 0, INSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1)
```

The total query:

```
FROM
    CUSTOMER_ORDER, IBT, IBT_LINE,PART, WORK_ORDER
WHERE
    CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = REPLACE(IBT.ID,'X','C') 
    AND IBT.ID = IBT_LINE.IBT_ID
    AND IBT_LINE.PART_ID=PART.ID
    AND SUBSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, 0, INSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1) = SUBSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, 0, INSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1) 
    AND WORK_ORDER.WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04' AND WORK_ORDER.STATUS  ='R'
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Why don't you just use the JOIN syntax rather than (+)?

Comment: what extra rows are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: I tried to use JOIN but does not work. I would like to have all information from WORK_ORDER table even that a similar union code does not exist on IBT_LINE table.

Comment: Please define "does not work"? Gives error? Returns results different then you want?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do a right/left join with two tables, and have a mandatory value on a field of that table in the same select. 
Your problem is not with sintax (+ or JOIN), yout problem is with your select.

You're trying to get an outer join in WORK_ORDER and IBT_LINE, but you are telling oracle to do a full join with this sentence:

....
   AND WORK_ORDER.WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04' AND WORK_ORDER.STATUS  ='R'

You can try a subselect in your FROM,

```
....
FROM
    CUSTOMER_ORDER, IBT, IBT_LINE,PART, 
     (SELECT SUBSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, 0, INSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1) user_1_formatted 
              from WORK_ORDER 
              where WORK_ORDER.WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04' 
              AND WORK_ORDER.STATUS  ='R') sub_work_order
WHERE
CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = REPLACE(IBT.ID,'X','C') 
    AND IBT.ID = IBT_LINE.IBT_ID
    AND IBT_LINE.PART_ID=PART.ID
    AND SUBSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, 0, INSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1) = sub_work_order.user_1_formatted(+)
```

or a subselect and then filter your results, as you wish.

```
select *
from (select ... from 
    CUSTOMER_ORDER, IBT, IBT_LINE,PART, WORK_ORDER
WHERE
    CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = REPLACE(IBT.ID,'X','C') 
    AND IBT.ID = IBT_LINE.IBT_ID
    AND IBT_LINE.PART_ID=PART.ID
    AND SUBSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, 0, INSTR(IBT_LINE.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1) = SUBSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, 0, INSTR(WORK_ORDER.USER_1, '-', +1, 3)-1) (+))
  where (work_order is null or (WORK_ORDER.WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04' AND WORK_ORDER.STATUS  ='R'))
```